# Magento 2 in admin panel side attributes drop down values not be save and delete?

Tags: magento2.2, admin-panel, magento-2.1.9

Attributes dropdown values not be save and delete in admin panel side

I have change the php.ini files max_input_vars=100000 but its not working?

[image]

Please give me any solutions..?

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue? i also face same issue. It only not working for dropdown attribute.